# Android Client and PC Server communication using sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am running a client on android emulator and server (java) on the same PC and am using socket programming. Attaching code below. Individually both are running fine but the actual data transfer is not happening and am not able to figure it out.

Server side(PC):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server_tcp {
    void run(){
        {
            try {
                System.out.println("In 1st try blck");
                try {
                    System.out.println("In 2nd try blck");
                    Boolean end = false;
                    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4444);
                    System.out.println("socket created");
                    while(!end){
                        //Server is waiting for client here, if needed
                        Socket s = ss.accept();
                        System.out.println("socket accepted");
                        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true); //Autoflush
                        String st = input.readLine();
                        System.out.println("Tcp Example" + "From client: "+st);
                        output.println("Good bye and thanks for all the fish :)");
                        s.close();
                        if (st==null){ end = true; }
                    }
                    ss.close();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Server_tcp server = new Server_tcp();
        while(true){
            server.run();
        }
    }
}
```

Client Side (Android ):

```
package com.try3;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ClientTCPActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private EditText et;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        System.out.println("Before try net");
        trynet();
        System.out.println("after try net");
    }
    public void trynet() {
        System.out.println("inside try net");
        try {
            System.out.println("inside try");
            Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",4444);

            //outgoing stream redirect to socket
            OutputStream out = (OutputStream) et.getContentDescription();

            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
            output.println("Hello Android!");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

            //read line(s)
            String st = input.readLine();
            System.out.println(st);

            //Close connection
            s.close();

            System.out.println(" try ");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Android Emulator you should be referring to your PC using 10.0.2.2 instead of 127.0.0.1

I didn't understand what you are trying to do here.

```
OutputStream out = (OutputStream) et.getContentDescription();
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
```

Did you mean something like:

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
```

??

Comment: If you are running this on HoneyComb SDK or higher, then this will throw a NetworkOnMainThreadException . So you will have to do the Socket Connection in a separate Thread.